# What CMake project structure to use: multiple apps, plugins, configurations

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for the idiomatic way to structure a project that has multiple applications (executables), plugin libraries (shared libs), and configurations (e.g. features.json) that are loaded at runtime.

Basically there are multiple physical devices that all share some common code.  Most of the common code is built as static libraries and linked into about half a dozen applications - one main application and several ancillary test applications.  The main application loads plugins at run time, but the plugins it loads depends on the device type.  Lastly, the plugins themselves have slightly different functionality depending on the features in features.json.  These features define things the device might have (e.g. WiFi or not, SDCard slot or not).

Is it idiomatic to create a unique top-level CMakeLists.txt file for each device and have each of those add_subdirectory the common folders and specific plugins?

```
Device1/CMakeLists.txt
(pulls in below via add_subdirectory)
 |_ LIBS
 |_ Apps
 |_ Plugin1
 |_ Plugin4

Device2/CMakeLists.txt
(pulls in below via add_subdirectory)
 |_ LIBS
 |_ Apps
 |_ Plugin2
 |_ Plugin3
```

The result of this is multiple build folders, one for each device type.  The top-level CMake file is responsible for choosing the appropriate plugins to build and copying/creating the appropriate features.json file to install with the plugins.

ALTERNATELY (case 2)

Have a generic top-level CMakeLists.txt and read in some kind of file at build time that lists the devices and try to create multiple 'install' areas within one build folder:

```
CMakeLists.txt
(pulls in below via add_subdirectory)
|_ LIBS
|_ Apps
|_ Plugin1
|_ Plugin2
|_ Plugin3
|_ Plugin4
```

This last project setup would require some cmake that would read a file containing the devices and what plugins they need and which feature file to copy to the appropriate area of the build folder.

OUTPUT (case 2):

```
Build
 |_device1_artifacts (APPS, Plugin1, Plugin4, features1.json)
 |_device2_artifacts (APPS, Plugin2, Plugin3, features2.json)
 |_ ...
```

The latter seems to minimize compile times and filesystem use (only one build folder), but it requires creating multiple 'install' locations for various targets for each device type.  I would look for existing projects, but in the open source world I can't think of a project that uses CMake and has to support multiple device configurations.